# Nifi security in public network

Tags: apache-nifi

*Is that secure to put Nifi into public network? If yes, what configs do I need?*

I have a single Nifi instance (vertical scaling is okay for my use case). I'm integrating Nifi with Azure Data Factory (ADF) through ListenHTTP processor (few HTTP calls daily). ADF Azure IR supports calling only public IPs: so I need public-facing API Gateway or public-facing Nifi. The issue is that I need the smallest possible API Gateway (20$/month on Azure), but Azure API Gateway supports Static IPs only from Standard tier (180$/month).

In the same time, Nifi has SSLContextService, and I have server certificate. As far as I understand, I can generate a client certificate and bind them. So I'm wondering if there is a simply way to configure security on Nifi side w/o Gateway.

*Is it secure to accept HTTP calls by ListenHTTP processor with configured SSL certificate?*

P.S. admin page ports can be closed for external networks.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, but a general observation: It seems like you are trying to meet Production level requirements while working with a budget that does not match that. If you are re-architecting now to save 160 bucks per month it is likely to be a painful road with security gaps along the way.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin the question is about public facing port required for ListenHTTP processor. Is it enough to protect it with SSL certificate and DN pattern? Do you know about any security gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let Nifi only listen to requests from a certain IP that should be reasonable. Even if that IP is public. If you want to be extra safe a firewall may add extra security.

If you open it up to the world (like it was earlier suggested for the GUI) that would be asking for trouble. At the very least you would be open to DDOS attacks as I don't think Nifi internally has protection against those.